# AttributeError when Initializing a Custom Decoder Class in TensorFlow with Non-Default Tokenizer

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, nlp, huggingface-transformers

I'm encountering an AttributeError while trying to create an instance of a Decoder class in Python with TensorFlow. The error message I'm getting is as follows:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-76-debfaa5162f4> in <cell line: 2>()
      1 # That will be sufficient for training. Create an instance of the decoder to test out:
----> 2 decoder = Decoder(tokenizer, UNITS)
      3 logits = decoder(ex_context, tf.expand_dims(ex_tar_in, axis=0))
      4 print(f'encoder output shape: (batch, s, units) {ex_context.shape}')
      5 print(f'input target tokens shape: (batch, t) {ex_tar_in.shape}')

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/layers/preprocessing/index_lookup.py in set_vocabulary(self, vocabulary, idf_weights)
    517             idf_weights = np.array(idf_weights)
    518 
--> 519         if vocabulary.size == 0:
    520             raise ValueError(
    521                 f"Cannot set an empty vocabulary, you passed {vocabulary}."

AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'size'
```

I suspect that the error is related to the usage of the `tf.keras.layers.StringLookup()` layer, which expects a 'size' attribute in the vocabulary. However, I'm not using the default TensorFlow tokenizer; I'm using the RobertaTokenizer from the Transformers library.
I tried manually adding variable to tokenizer but it doesnot work.

This code is adapted from the [NNCourse](https://www.tensorflow.org/text/tutorials/nmt_with_attention#the_decoder), and I've made some modifications to it.

Here is my decoder code:

```
# The decoder
"""
The decoder's job is to generate predictions for the next token at each 
location in the target sequence.

The Decoder Structure:
1. It looks up embeddings for each token in the target sequence.
2. It uses an RNN to process the target sequence, and keep track of what it has generated so far.
3. It uses RNN output as the "query" to the attention layer, when attending to the encoder's output.
4. At each location in the output it predicts the next token.

Note:
When training, the model predicts the next word at each location. So it's 
important that the information only flows in one direction through the model. 
The decoder uses a unidirectional (not bidirectional) 
RNN to process the target sequence.

> When running inference with this model it produces one word at a time, 
and those are fed back into the model.
"""

class Decoder(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
  
  @classmethod
  def add_method(cls, fun):
    setattr(cls, fun.__name__, fun)
    return fun

  def __init__(self, text_processor, units):
    super(Decoder, self).__init__()
    self.text_processor = text_processor  # Tokenizer
    self.vocab_size = text_processor.size  # Vocab size
    # https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/StringLookup
    self.word_to_id = tf.keras.layers.StringLookup(
        vocabulary=text_processor.vocab,
        mask_token=text_processor.mask_token,
        oov_token=text_processor.unk_token)
    
    # https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/StringLookup
    self.id_to_word = tf.keras.layers.StringLookup(
        vocabulary=text_processor.vocab,
        mask_token=text_processor.mask_token,
        oov_token=text_processor.unk_token,
        invert=True)
    
    self.start_token = self.word_to_id(START_TOKEN)
    self.end_token = self.word_to_id(END_TOKEN)

    self.units = units


    # 1. The embedding layer converts token IDs to vectors
    self.embedding = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(self.vocab_size,
                                               units, mask_zero=True)

    # 2. The RNN keeps track of what's been generated so far.
    self.rnn = tf.keras.layers.GRU(units,
                                   return_sequences=True,
                                   return_state=True,
                                   recurrent_initializer='glorot_uniform')

    # 3. The RNN output will be the query for the attention layer.
    self.attention = CrossAttention(units)

    # 4. This fully connected layer produces the logits for each
    # output token.
    self.output_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(self.vocab_size)
```

> Specs: Python = 3.8 tensorflow = 2.14.0 transformers = 4.34.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

It was solved by separating the tokenizer from model and removing the `tf.keras.layers.StringLookup` layer as it only works on tensorflow vectorizer/tokenizer.